# VBA Function to list all precedents/descendants to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code to find all dependents and precedents for a cell. Unfortunately the code only returns a reference to itself by first using the ShowDependents/ShowPrecedents methods and then looping over the NavigateArrow to set my cell of interest, and then storing the address of that cell in a string. When I check the .Precedents.Count or .Dependents.Count both only return a value of 1 no matter the number of actual dependents/precedents there are and I have tested the NavigateArrow method in Debug.Print and no matter what I do to the ArrowNumber or LinkNumber arguments I do not see any change in the referenced cell.

My current function is

```
Function findEnds(rng As Range) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo ExitErr
    With rng
        .ShowPrecedents
        Do While i < .Precedents.Count
            i = i + 1
            Set crng = .NavigateArrow(True, i, 1)
            str = str & vbCrLf & vbTab & crng.Address(External:=True)
        Loop
        .Parent.ClearArrows
        str = str & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "DEPENDENTS:::"
        .ShowDependents
        i = 0
        Do While i < .Dependents.Count
            i = i + 1
            Set crng = .NavigateArrow(False, i, 1)
            str = str & vbCrLf & vbTab & crng.Address(External:=True)
        Loop
    End With
ExitErr:
findEnds = str
End Function
```

The idea here is to first store the precedents and then store the decedents.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a better excuse for writing a recursive procedure/function in Excel-VBA :-)

Comment: @Dominique - how do you mean? I probably should have been clearer and added that I was only interested in one level of relationships. Are you suggesting using recursive code to deal with the entire tree of relationships? For that, I think the Inquire add on does a pretty good job already.

Comment: I was talking about the entire tree indeed. I have never heard of the Inquire add-on.

Comment: @Dominique - oh, it's pretty cool and I highly recommend. It can be a bit clunky and slow, but it includes an bunch of tools like analysis report, file comparison, password repository etc.

Comment: If you're calling that function from a worksheet cell then functions called like that are limited in what they can do, so you may be seeing the result of that.  Do you see the same result when calling the function from VBA?

Comment: Yea - I think the issue might be related to some kind of bug. I tried the method described here which is a routine generating a msgbox, and it seems to work. 

https://excelhelphq.com/how-to-find-all-dependent-cells-outside-of-worksheet-and-workbook-in-excel-vba/

the issue would seem to be to do with some bug around generating that list when on the current sheet is active, and the routine activates another sheet while it's building the list. I can't think of a way to do something similar with a UDF where the UDF would typically be used on the same sheet as the equation of interest